# How can I verify the order in which keys are pressed on a piano keyboard?

Tags: javascript, html, web, combinations, verification

I have created this piano keyboard. It has sound but I can't add that in the snippet. The sound is triggered by the `onclick` attribute for each key and played thanks to a function in js. I would like to verify that the user presses the keys with the following ids in the following order: c c g g a a g, then alert "Success!". What is the shortest way I can do it?

```css
#piano {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.key {
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.white {
  height: 220px;
  width: 50px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-right: none;
  z-index: 0;
}

.white:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.white:hover {
  filter: brightness(90%);
}

.white:active {
  filter: brightness(70%);
}

.black {
  position: absolute;
  height: 130px;
  width: 31px;
  background: black;
  z-index: 1;
}

.black:hover {
  background: #0f0f0f;
}

.black:active {
  background: #0a0a0a;
}

#c-sharp {
  margin-left: 36px;
}

#d-sharp {
  margin-left: 87px;
}

#f-sharp {
  margin-left: 189px;
}

#g-sharp {
  margin-left: 240px;
}

#a-sharp {
  margin-left: 291px;
}
```

```html
<div id="piano">
  <span class="white key" id="c"></span>
  <span class="black key" id="c-sharp"></span>
  <span class="white key" id="d"></span>
  <span class="black key" id="d-sharp"></span>
  <span class="white key" id="e"></span>
  <span class="white key" id="f"></span>
  <span class="black key" id="f-sharp"></span>
  <span class="white key" id="g"></span>
  <span class="black key" id="g-sharp"></span>
  <span class="white key" id="a"></span>
  <span class="black key" id="a-sharp"></span>
  <span class="white key" id="b"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach would look something like this:

add an eventListener to each span and when its clicked append its id to a string called pressed. After you added the id (for example 'a') you compare it to your specified order.

This should do the trick in the most simple way :)

```js
let pressed = '';

document.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    pressed += item.id;
    if( pressed == 'ccggaag' ) {
      alert("Success");
    } else {
      console.log(pressed);
    }
  })
})
```

```css
#piano {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.key {
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.white {
  height: 220px;
  width: 50px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-right: none;
  z-index: 0;
}

.white:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.white:hover {
  filter: brightness(90%);
}

.white:active {
  filter: brightness(70%);
}

.black {
  position: absolute;
  height: 130px;
  width: 31px;
  background: black;
  z-index: 1;
}

.black:hover {
  background: #0f0f0f;
}

.black:active {
  background: #0a0a0a;
}

#c-sharp {
  margin-left: 36px;
}

#d-sharp {
  margin-left: 87px;
}

#f-sharp {
  margin-left: 189px;
}

#g-sharp {
  margin-left: 240px;
}

#a-sharp {
  margin-left: 291px;
}
```

```html
<div id="piano">
  <span class="white key" id="c"></span>
  <span class="black key" id="c-sharp"></span>
  <span class="white key" id="d"></span>
  <span class="black key" id="d-sharp"></span>
  <span class="white key" id="e"></span>
  <span class="white key" id="f"></span>
  <span class="black key" id="f-sharp"></span>
  <span class="white key" id="g"></span>
  <span class="black key" id="g-sharp"></span>
  <span class="white key" id="a"></span>
  <span class="black key" id="a-sharp"></span>
  <span class="white key" id="b"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, thanks to those who answered! I wanted to try and make it without using jQuery, as I don't know it. This way I made it so that if the user gets one button wrong they don't have to recharge the page, instead they can just go on and try again. It's a very "bulky" method, so maybe someone can improve it, yet it does the trick :)

```js
var y = "";

function melody(x) {
  y += x;
  if (y == "c" ||
    y == "cc" ||
    y == "ccg" ||
    y == "ccgg" ||
    y == "ccgga" ||
    y == "ccggaa" ||
    y == "ccggaag"
  ) {
    if (y == "ccggaag") {
      alert("Success!");
    }
  } else y = "";
}
```

```css
#piano {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.key {
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.white {
  height: 220px;
  width: 50px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-right: none;
  z-index: 0;
}

.white:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.white:hover {
  filter: brightness(90%);
}

.white:active {
  filter: brightness(70%);
}

.black {
  position: absolute;
  height: 130px;
  width: 31px;
  background: black;
  z-index: 1;
}

.black:hover {
  background: #0f0f0f;
}

.black:active {
  background: #0a0a0a;
}

#c-sharp {
  margin-left: 36px;
}

#d-sharp {
  margin-left: 87px;
}

#f-sharp {
  margin-left: 189px;
}

#g-sharp {
  margin-left: 240px;
}

#a-sharp {
  margin-left: 291px;
}
```

```html
<div id="piano">
  <span class="white key" id="c" onclick="melody('c')"></span>
  <span class="black key" id="c-sharp" onclick="melody('c#')"></span>
  <span class="white key" id="d" onclick="melody('d')"></span>
  <span class="black key" id="d-sharp" onclick="melody('d#')"></span>
  <span class="white key" id="e" onclick="melody('e')"></span>
  <span class="white key" id="f" onclick="melody('f')"></span>
  <span class="black key" id="f-sharp" onclick="melody('f#')"></span>
  <span class="white key" id="g" onclick="melody('g')"></span>
  <span class="black key" id="g-sharp" onclick="melody('g#')"></span>
  <span class="white key" id="a" onclick="melody('a')"></span>
  <span class="black key" id="a-sharp" onclick="melody('a#')"></span>
  <span class="white key" id="b" onclick="keysound(b); melody('b')"></span>
</div>
```